# JS, CSS, HTML5 вопрос по динамическому отслеживанию посетителя

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, анимация, keyframes

Всем доброго времени суток. Начал я тут обновлять свои познания в css, и вдруг пришла мысль(возможно я где-то это видел), как отследить, например на лендинге, что человек просматривает именно какой-то кусок страницы.
Что я имею в виду:
Человек зашел на сайт, посмотрел , почитал, далее скроллом пошел вниз, и когда он дошел до определенного блока, то начинается воспроизведение анимации, написанной на сss. Т.е. если рассматривать Landing, то он состоит, предположим, из 4 блоков, и на каждом блоке, при просмотре пользователем, начинается анимациz, например появление текста снизу в верх при помощи keyframes и animation.

Comment: В чём вопрос то?

Comment: @Khipster, _как отследить, например на лендинге, что человек просматривает именно какой-то кусок страницы._

Comment: В общем случае - задача не решаема, так как **никак** нельзя определить что именно **просматривает** человек. Вполне себе ситуация - пользователь прокручивал сайт, а потом просто отошел от компьютера/телефона и т.д. С точки зрения человека - он **не** просматривает этот кусок кода, но скрипт это **никак** отследить не может. Если конечно нет доступа к вебке, по которой можно получить изображение пользователя и определить в какую часть экрана он смотрит

Comment: @Grundy Вы не учитываете возможность возникновения в прицеле веб-камеры объекта типа кот. Так что веб-камера не панацея.

Comment: @Khipster, конечно учитываю

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать wow.js в связке с animation.css, там можно это все сделать. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gMYtFGjg3s

Answer (score 0):

Используйте JavaScript-событие scroll.

Comment: И как по скроллу, по вашему, отследить на какой части находится человек, учитывая, что применяется адаптивная верстка и размер экрана будет меняться.

Comment: @KamilNHOT, внутри обработчика доступно текущее смещение - это вполне подходит под _какой-то кусок_.